# No common supported orientation bug on 3.1.6 version of Appgyver steroids(ios)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is there a way we can set the webview orientation on appgyver 3.1.6? We can't use the latest 3.5.1> version because we are using a audio encode plugin which doesn't work on the latest version. So, we stick on using the 3.1.6 which we are having pop up message that no common supported orientation.. This is annoying really.. I know this is fixed on the latest version. But how am I able to set this one?

Plugin used:
https://github.com/wootwoot1234/cordova-phonegap-audio-encode.git

Appgyver build: 3.1.6-p4

Answer (score 0):

Just for others stumbling on this thread, the problem was fixed in a roundabout way by updating the plugin linked in the original question to work with newer AppGyver runtimes. The discussion can be found in [this thread](https://forums.appgyver.com/#!/steroids-bugs:no-common-supported-orienta).